# 2 index appropriate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a few very brief questions that are all related, that I dont think warrant a separate post for each

1. if i have a User model (Devise gem) that contains both "username" and "email" attributes, and both are unique, do i add_index to both of them or just one? Only one key is "needed" for this particular table as a foreign key, i just dont know if i should add_index for both of them.
2. how do i reorder the validations that happen on the front end of my form? Right now the validation messages for :username are at the bottom yet its the first field on the form, so they should be at the top. this is after i added fields to the devise gem, so im guessing the devise validations run first before mine.
3. is it frowned upon to edit the db migrate file for the devise gem or should i do rails g migration for each change i want to make?. My app is not in production yet, but I just saw some tutorials where everyone recommended this step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) The index will be used for looking up rows from the Users table so if you will be looking up users by their email, then you may add an index for email as well as username. Otherwise username alone should be fine.

(3) Yes it is frowned upon to edit a migration file that's already been run because it becomes difficult to keep track of changes and you could end up in a situation where you can't roll back only the part you edited. So you should create a new migration whenever you need to make a db change. However since your app is not in production yet, depending on how much data you have, there may not be much harm in doing so. Your call.

Comment: If you need to guarantee uniqueness by email you should still add a unique index on that field, even if you're not going to query it.

Comment: Agreed. @Russell is right, you should add a unique index if you need to impose that condition on the table.

Answer (score 1):

On 1: It depends on how rigorous you want to be and in what way. On the one hand, since it's so cheap and easy to add a unique constraint/index on both fields (I'm assuming a traditional SQL schema), why wouldn't you? On the other, some rails purists argue (with good reason) that you should forgo any database vendor specifics and enforce all constraints in the rails model, and then add indexes (not constraints) as a performance optimization. I'm old skool, so I prefer the former, but I'm also a purist, so I make sure my rails models are right and my applications never rely on db vendor specifics.

On 2: I would handle validation error display in the view layer, i.e., don't get hung up on the order they are run - think of all the validations as an atomic operation. Then, in the view, instead of just dumping the error messages in the order they happen to be in, reorder the hash or even test and output each key explicitly. It's a little less maintainable, in that if you add a new input you would need to update that view code. But, that is minor compared to the headache of trying to maintain the order the validations are run. Personally, I don't believe the order the error messages are printed is even relevant, but I know is rubs some people the wrong way.

On 3: Agree with Sebi, do not edit gems or anything gems provide, and do not edit migrations retroactively. It's trivial to add a new migration, so just do it and move on to the interesting stuff. If I am the only programmer on an application not in production, I'll take the shortcut, but as soon as it's live or there's another developer, I am more disciplined. And, the more time I spend programming rails, I find writing rails db migrations just as easy as or easier than SQL.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. As a sidenote, on question 2, how might i reorder the hash? I'm kind of new to this. <%= devise_error_messages! %>